figma groupnode children does not load when consoled, there is a delay

I m working on a figma plugin using figma plugin api, but when im
trying to get all children FrameNodes from rdLayer[0].children then
only 1 FrameNode is consoled, but when setTimeout is used then it
gives all FrameNodes from the rdLayer[0].children,

const getReadoutLayer = async (mainLayer: GroupNode, setId: string ): Promise<boolean> => {
    let rdLayer: GroupNode[];

    if (mainLayer) {
        rdLayer = mainLayer.children.filter((layer) => layer.name === readoutLayerName) as GroupNode[];
    }

    let frameChildren: FrameNode[];

    if (rdLayer && rdLayer.length) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            frameChildren = rdLayer[0].children.filter(child => child.type === 'FRAME') as FrameNode[];

            console.log("--0--", frameChildren)
            console.log("--1--", setId)
            console.log("--2--", !!frameChildren.find(x => x.name === setId))

            return !!frameChildren.find(x => x.name === setId);
        }, 2000);
    }

    return false;
}   

    let autolayoutFrame: FrameNode;

    const isExistingFrame: boolean = await getReadoutLayer(mainLayer, set[0].set.id);
    console.log("isExistingFrame:", isExistingFrame)


How can i avoid setTimeout and get all FrameNodes from children at
once ?

